# Stalks of Plane Conic $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ are UFD

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, local-rings

Assume $k$ is a alg closed field. Then it is easy to check that the morphism $\phi: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2, (x_0:x_1) \mapsto (x_0^2: x_0x_1:x_1^2)$ induces an isomorphism between $\mathbb{P}^1$ and homogeneous curve $C=V_+(y_0^2-y_1^2 +_2^2)$ as follows:

The image of $ \mathbb{P}^1 $ by $\phi$ is $V_+(XZ-Y^2)$ and if we make substitution $X:= y_0+iy_2, Z:= y_0-iy_2$ and $Y:=y_1$ we obtain the equation for $C$.

This curve has homogeneous coordinate ring $k[y_0,y_1,y_2]/(y_0^2-y_1^2 +y_2^2)$. We know that since $\mathbb{P}^1$ is regular every stalk $\mathcal{\mathbb{P}^1,p}$ is a regular local ring = a UFD since $\mathbb{P}^1$ integral of dimension $1$.

Since $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong C$ every stalk of $C$ at arbitrary closed point has to be also a UFD. Unfortunately, I not see why this is true if we forget $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong C$ and try to do the calculation of $\mathcal{O}_{C,c}$ by hand. Consider the affine $D_+(y_0)$-chart, then we have to prove that every localization of the affine ring $k[y,z]/(1-y^2 +z^2)$ at any maximal prime of $k[y,z]/(1-y^2 +z^2)$ (ie every prime exept $(1-y^2 +z^2)$ is a UFD. How can this claim be checked?

Comment: First, how did you get your equation, $y_0^2-y_1^2+y_2^2$?

Comment: @Mohan: I think I was a bit too quick und overjumped an inportant intermediate step. The image of $\phi$ is given by $V_+(XZ-Y^2)$ and if we make substitution $X:= y_0+iy_2, Z:= y_0-iy_2$ and $Y:=y_1$ we obtain the equation you asked for

Comment: Then, why not check the UFD property using $XZ-Y^2$, where it is easier?

Comment: @Mohan: yes, that's true. I think if we treat $C$ as $V_+(XZ-Y^2)$ I understand the solution: using symmetry we deal with affine pieces $D_+(X)$ and $D_+(Y)$: in first case $k[Y,Z]/(Y-Z^2)=k[Z]$ and every localization of $k[Z]$ is UFD. for $D_+(Y)$ we have $k[X,Y]/(XY-1)= K[X]_{(X)}$ is also UFD, that's all.

Comment: a little nitpick: if we assume that $k$ is not more algebraically closed and $i \not \in k$. That means we cannot do the transformation  $X:= y_0+iy_2, Z:= y_0-iy_2$ and $Y:=y_1$ and therefore over this $k$ the subvarieties  $V_+(XZ-Y^2) $ and $V_+(y_0^2-y_1^2 +_2^2)$ of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ not look isomorphically.

Comment: Nevertheless, are all stalks of $C_k:=V_+(y_0^2-y_1^2 +_2^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^1_k$ at maximal primes UFD's also for this $k$? In this case, we cannot reduce the calculations of stalks to the calculation of stalks of  $V_+(XZ-Y^2) $ since because $i \not \in k$ implies that a trafo as above in this world not more exist.

Comment: If we deal with $D_+(y_0)$-chart, and set $y:=y_1/y_0, z:=y_2/y_0$ then we have to show that every localization of the affine ring $k[y,z]/(1-y^2 +z^2)$ at any maximal prime of $k[y,z]/(1-y^2 +z^2)$ is a UFD. or find a conterexample. Do you have a hint  how to prove or disprove the claim in this case?