# Localizations of $k[x,y]/(f)$ UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring in two indeterminants and $f \in k[x,y] \backslash k$ a non constant poynomial.

I want to know if there exist any nice criteria to answer the question when the quotient $R:=k[x,y]/(f)$ has the property that *every localization* at every maximal prime of $R$ is UFD.

The notation "nice" quantifies the generality of the application (preferably a wide class of different polynomials) and non triviality of the seeked criterion. eg a "boring" sufficient criterion is to require that $f$ contains a linear term $ax$ or $by$. Thus we can a priori assume that $f$ not contains linear terms.

The question is closely related to this one and considered as a far generalization of it: [Localizations of $k[y,z]/(1-y^2+z^2)$ UFDs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692493/localizations-of-ky-z-1-y2z2-ufds)

Comment: IIRC the key concept is that of a [DVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the condition you are looking for holds. Then the curve defined by $f$ is normal, since UFDs are integrally closed. But normalization is a resolution of singluarities in dimension 1, so if $k$ is, for example, algebraically closed, you end up with a smooth curve (and obviously the converse holds).

Comment: About one point I'm not sure. You implicitly use that that to require that all localizations of $R:=k[x,y]/(f)$ at maximal primes is equivalently to all lacalizations to be DVR's. Is it true? A characterization of a DVR is "is a unique factorization domain with a unique irreducible element (up to multiplication by units)." (see wiki) but this "unique irreducible element" seems to be a proper *additional* condition. That is in genral it can happen that a maximal ideal of a UFD of dimension $1$ is not principal, or not?

Comment: Since you have a curve, (let us suppose it is irreducible and k is algebraically closed), you only have 2 kinds of points : closed points and one generic point. In other words, if $f$ is irreducible, the only prime ideal of $k[X,Y]/f$ which is not maximal is the zero ideal.In general what you mention doesn't apply, because DVRs have krull dimension 1. As for your last question, a local *noetherian* UFD of dimension 1 is automaticaly a DVR and it is principal.

Comment: That's an interesting point: do you know where I can look up for the statement that a  local noetherian UFD of dimension $1$ is a DVR? Another point is if you know how to deal with the story if $k$ is *not* algebraically closed. indeed, in case in alg closed case regular scheme is equivalent to smooth one and we can check derivatives of $f$ with Jacobian criterion, so far I understand that. When $k$ is not alg closed it can hapen that the fiber product of the base change of the curve to alg closure it not more smooth, but the curve itself over $k$ was probably regular.

Comment: Do you know how to deal with this case?

Comment: For the DVR thing, you can check theorem 11.2 p.79 in Matsumura's "Commutative ring theory". For the case where $k$ is a general field, I believe the equivalence between regular and smooth still holds if $k$ is perfect, and for the other ones, I do not know.